# DAX calculating the age of a ticket in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have table named 'Tickets' which holds all the Tickets. I'm trying to calculate the age of a ticket since its creation. The Tickets table has a column called 'Ticket'[CreateDate]. I have tried DatesBetween and DatesInPeriod but not quite getting the right data, I'm new to DAX and still trying to figure out the functions, please help.

Adding picture of the data type of the CreatedDate and ClosedDate columns.

[image]

Comment: How does your data look?Are there multiple records for a ticket or is it just one record?Is there a closed date in your data? Sample data and desired output are a huge help in these scenarios

Comment: @CR7SMS yes the Ticket table has several thousand records. And yes there is a ClosedDate field

Comment: Check out the answer below to see if it works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date fields are not formatted properly, you would have to create calculated columns for Createdate and Closedate:

```
Createdate1 = Date(Left([Createdate ],4),Right(left([Createdate ],6),2),right([Createdate ],2)
Closedate1= Date(Left([Closedate],4),Right(left([Closedate],6),2),right([Closedate],2)
```

You have to use the `DATEDIFF` function to find the difference between dates.

If you are just looking for the age as of today:

```
Age = DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate1],TODAY(),DAY)
```

If you have a closed date in your table:

```
Age = DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate1],'Table'[ClosedDate1],DAY)
```

If you are looking for something else, please provide sample data and the output required.

Edit:

If you want to use both for Open and Closed tickets:

```
Age = IF('Table'[TicketStatus]="Open",
         DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate1],TODAY(),DAY),
         DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate1],'Table'[ClosedDate1],DAY))
```

Comment: Okay great, I'm thinking to try both in an =IF([TicketStatus]='Open',Age = DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate],TODAY(),DAY), DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate],'Table'[ClosedDate],DAY))

Comment: Added that to the answer as well

Comment: thanks! but I got an error when tried with the IF, firstly I could only able to used the 'Table'[TicketStatus]="Open" when using it in a Calculated Column. Then I got this error "An Invalid numeric representation of date value was encountered"

Comment: Can you try just one of the calculations and see if it works, maybe just DATEDIFF('Table'[CreateDate],TODAY(),DAY)....And this is meant to be a calculated column...

Comment: Yup tried it, unfortunately the same error. I think its having problem with the date format of the columns. the date format is YYYYMMDD

Comment: That should not matter, as long as the field is formatted as a date...Under the modelling tab check the format of the field, if it is not a date, change it to a date

Comment: Yes I checked CreateDate and ClosedDate, both of these are in **WholeNumber** Data type with **General** format, **Date** Data type is grayed out.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how the data looks like?

Comment: You have to convert the fields into date format. You have to create calculated columns: dateFormatted = Date(Left([date],4),Right(left([date],6),2),right([date],2)